# How to customize Table Calendar header in flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar, header, customization

**Default Table Calendar Header:**
[image]

**Expected Header:**
[image]

The Default Calendar header showing the icons left and right side of the screen and text in center. But I want to customize like second image.

I have tried header style method to only change the colors and styles but not changing their positions. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you, which is what I did myself in a similar situation, is to create your own header and link it to the callendar.
You can do this by hiding the callendar's original header with

```
headerVisible: false
```

Then you can add a Row() for example and add the widgets you wish

Comment: Can't understand where to add Row() ?

Comment: If you want to build your own custom calendar, you can use a structure like

`Column( children : [ /* Header*/  Row(), TableCalendar()])`

So you had a row to the top of the calendar, which you can customize. The hard thing then is to link those components to the calendar itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
headerTitleBuilder: (context, day) {
return Row(
mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAligment.center,
children:[Text("March",Row(children:[Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
],),),],),
  },
),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?